# node ssh-exec pipe some data to the remote process

Tags: node.js, ssh

sorry maybe doing something wrong but can't find anything in the output file, see below:

```
var exec = require('ssh-exec');
var fs = require('fs');
file = fs.createWriteStream('rep-output.txt');
    process.stdin
     .pipe(exec(command, host))
     .pipe(file);
file.end();
```

here it is:

```
[node]$ cat rep-output.txt 
[node]$
```

but because 'command' is 'touch output.txt' I can see it executed correctly on remote 'host':

```
[remote]$ ls -l output.txt 
[remote]$-rw-rw-r-- 1 irekr irekr 0 Jul  4 10:53 output.txt
```

if 'command' is  i.e. 'ls -l' still 'rep-output.txt' is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you are closing the stream before writing started. Remove `file.end()`

```
file = fs.createWriteStream('rep-output.txt');
process.stdin
 .pipe(exec(command, host))
 .pipe(file);
```

When you `pipe` streams it will take care of ending writing stream when the input stream ends. See [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options):

> By default end() is called on the destination when the source stream
>   emits end, so that destination is no longer writable. Pass { end:
>   false } as options to keep the destination stream open.

Comment: Thnx , it worked. When I am supposed to close file then ?

Comment: Thnx one more question, sorry when I schedule this code in Linux cron then it doesn't work . I tried absolute paths etc didn't help . it works fine (sends email)  if I comment all this code and i.e. ask to email something to me i.e.    /*process.stdin
        .pipe(exec(command, host))
        .pipe(file);*/    
    email.send(config.emailTo, emailText, emailSubject, emailAttach);

Comment: you are probably saving the file in a cron working directory. use `cd` in cron command to change dirctory and then run the script.

Comment: that 'rep-output.txt' is in the same directory I am running node from. 
[root@node dev-test]# crontab -l
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/node /home/irek/repvpn/dev-test/dev-repcert.js >> /home/irek/repvpn/dev-test/dev-repcert.log > /dev/null 2>&1 
[root@nms01m dev-test]# pwd
/home/irek/repvpn/dev-test
[root@node dev-test]# ls -l rep-output.txt 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 irek irek 0 Jul  4 11:45 rep-output.txt